# Yocto Project: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS keeps crashing when running: bitbake fsl-image-gui

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, embedded-linux, yocto

Currently using a Dell-Precision-T1650 Machine with 8 GB of RAM, Intel Core i5 Processor (3.3GHz), and an external (USB Connected) Western Digital Hard-drive (3 TB).

The external drive has Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running and am able to boot from that drive.

I am currently building a Yocto Sumo image for my Variscite Dart-iMX8M-Mini Board using a custom Yocto build downloaded from: http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Build_Release&release=RELEASE_SUMO_V2.2_DART-MX8M-MINI

I am able to successfully complete all the steps, but when I get to my final step of building the actual image using: bitbake fsl-image-gui

My computer begins to crash at ~80% completion.No error signs are generated before the crash happens, as the computer just goes blank and asks for my login password. I have to restart the terminal and re-initiate the bitbake command.

I am not sure why this keeps happening as I have tried it on two identical machines and am getting the same malfunction on both.

I have also installed all the appropriate packages and the only warning / error sign I get while building is this:

> WARNING: /home/midi/var-fsl-yocto/sources/meta-variscite-imx/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-variscite_4.14.98.bb.do_compile is tainted from a forced run

Any help would be much appreciated.

Best,
Mickey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't make it clear if you are being logged out, or the machine is rebooting.

Spontaneous rebooting is usually caused by thermal overload (an hour of compiling can easily cause insufficient cooling to overhead the processor) or damaged RAM (compiling takes a lot of memory). Run something like `memtest86` to verify that your RAM is good, and use a processor temperature monitor to see if you hit any thermal limits that cause a reboot.

Logging out is most likely the out-of-memory killer running.  You can check this by looking at the `dmesg` output after it happens. If this is the case then you need more RAM.

Comment: Hello Ross, thank you for your comment. It's actually a little weird. While the terminal is processing, the computer screen suddenly goes black but instantaneously goes back to the login screen. It resembles being logged out since the ubuntu logo or the manufacturer's logo (Dell) doesn't appear. However, all the applications that were open are suddenly closed. I'm checking the dmesg now and see what the output is.

Comment: Just ran a memory checker and RAM had passed all segments. What's odd is that it crashes every time it tries to run this task: ltp-20180118-r0 Do_package. It's able to run all the other tasks successfully aside from this one. But I still don't understand why it won't spit out an error and just randomly reboot / log out.

Comment: This sounds like an existing, somewhat old bug: 
   system spontaneously logs out while building core-image
   https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11802
I think you can work-around it by sshing to localhost and doing your build there but it would be good to actually fix the issue since it's such a bad experience!

Comment: It's not a bug in yocto though, it's either the OOM killer or some other throttling.  ltp is a *huge* package and very intensive to package.  If you can identify *what* is actually causing the death (syslog or dmesg will give you a hint) that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a work around.
Open your local.conf file and set the **BB_NUMBER_THREADS ?= "1"**
Save the file. Run Bitbake again.
Hope this helps!!